# How to create unique values in one column and merge all other values from the second column?

Tags: r, dplyr, data-transform

I have a data frame that looks like this.

```
df <- data.frame(year = c(1978, 1978, 1979, 1979), bus = c("29C", "12B", "25G", "27C"))
```

I wish to create unique values for year column and merge the values of the bus column.
Expected output is as follows

```
# year  bus
# 1978  29C,12B
# 1979  25G,27C
```

The code I have tried and the output I have got

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(year) %>% distinct(year) %>% unite(bus, sep = ",", na.rm = F)

# A tibble: 2 x 1
# bus  
#  <chr>
#1 1978 
#2 1979
```

What is the mistake in the code and how can I achieve the expected output?

Comment: `df %>% group_by(year) %>% summarise(bus = toString(bus))`

Answer (score 1):

(EDIT after comment)

One possible solution would be

```
df %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  summarise(bus = paste(bus, collapse = ","))
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
# Groups:   year [2]
#    year bus    
#   <dbl> <chr>  
# 1  1978 29C,12B
# 2  1979 25G,27C
```

Comment: Why not `summarise()` instead of `mutate() %>% distinct()`?

Comment: It was the first solution that came to mind, but I agree that `summarise` is more efficient (and uses one less statement). Thank you for pointing that out!